# Does using HTML header tags as links have any SEO downside?

Tags: seo, html, links, pagerank

My homepage has several internal links which I would like to use as header tags.

For example: `<h2> <a href="http://www.example.com/about/"> About example.com </a> </h2>`

Does this pass PageRank to these internal links and therefore take some away from the homepage?

Is there any SEO downside to using header tags as links, as exemplified above?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. This is normal and common. The best example of this being Wordpress blog post headers  and StackExchange question headers. The title of this question is a link and an `<h1>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would accept that as standard practice. Just ensure that H1 is the first heading tag to appear on the page.

There is more information from Google themselves on [Site Title and Heading Tags](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en).

Answer (score -2):

This will just help you mostly. Internal linking was always beneficial for a website.

Comment: Do you have any references to backing that statement?